Set a field to proper case using INITCAP in Postgres but only after the first comma
I have a field that is currently formatted like this:
CAT5, NETWORK CABLE, 5

I want to change the NETWORK CABLE to Network Cable, but leave the CAT5 all caps. There can be 2 or more commas in the field. Any ideas, suggestions, or answers are appreciated.
I am not very familiar with regex but found this code to set only the last section of letters to UPPER:
SET description = INITCAP(regexp_replace(description, '[^,]+$', '')) || (regexp_match(description, '[^,]+$'))[1]

I want the first set only before the first comma. I could use INITCAP to reformat the whole field and then set the first section to UPPER. But how would I stop at the comma? This is in Postgres 12.

The following expression will perform the described operation:
SET description = SPLIT_PART(description, ',', 1) || COALESCE(INITCAP((REGEXP_MATCH(description, ',.*$'))[1]), '')

SPLIT_PART is more efficient than using a regular expression to extract the portion of the string prior to the first comma. COALESCE is used to guard against a description that doesn't include a comma.
